# is the environment variable IBM_HEAPDUMP enabled by default in IBM J9 JVM?

Tags: jvm, websphere, j9

i wonder if the environment variable `IBM_HEAPDUMP` enabled by default in IBM J9? I searched through the internet and somebody say it is while other say not. Let me suppose if it's active by default, that means, the signal-based heapdump has been enabled. And JVM would catch all the pre-defined signal and generate heapdump accordingly. 
  However, if so like above, why do we still need to configure with `-Xdump:what`? just as link described `http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21246238`. 
  The another question is whether `IBM_HEAPDUMP` and `-Xdump:what` are functioning overlap here? Or i'm totally understanding wrongly with these two.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding :-)

-Xdump:what doesn't configure anything.  It simply shows what dumps are enabled on the JVM in question.  Thus you can look at the output from -Xdump:what to see what's enabled.  By default, yes, there's dumps enabled like IBM_HEAPDUMP but you may want more control/detail.

Comment: Thanks very much @Trent Gray-Donald